# Correct usage of Monitor.PulseAll?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm writing our own logger for the ASP.NET Application that we're running. With the current code base we seem to have a threading issue, and I'm trying to eliminate component by component to find the cause of this issue. The symptons are CPU reaching 100% on the webserver once the application is started.

The first thing I want to eliminate is the logger I wrote, since that's one of the latest additions to the code base. The idea behind the logger is as follows:

- 1 static class called LogManager that tracks all ILogger implementations
- 1 static class called LogSettings that tracks all settings from a config file.
- 1 XmlLogger that has a MessageQueue to hold message and write them in an xml file.

The static class can be called from anywhere and the XmlLogger has a background thread that takes a message from the MessageQueue and processes it. So I need to make the access to this queue thread-safe. The code for the MessageQueue class looks like this:

```
public sealed class MessageQueue
    {
        #region Private Fields

        private readonly Queue<IMessage> _messageQueue;

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        /// <summary>
        /// <para>Creates a new instance of the class and initializes all internal fields.</para>
        /// </summary>
        public MessageQueue()
        {
            _messageQueue = new Queue<IMessage>();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// <para>Gets the number of <see cref="IMessage"/> objects in the queue.</para>
        /// </summary>
        public int NumberOfMessage
        {
            get
            {
                lock(_messageQueue)
                {
                    return _messageQueue.Count;
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Members

        /// <summary>
        /// <para>Adds a new <see cref="IMessage"/> to the bottom of the queue.</para>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">The <see cref="IMessage"/> to be added to the queue.</param>
        public void AddMessage(IMessage message)
        {
            lock(_messageQueue)
            {
                _messageQueue.Enqueue(message);
                Monitor.PulseAll(_messageQueue);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// <para>Gets the first <see cref="IMessage"/> from the queue.</para>
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The first <see cref="IMessage"/> from the queue.</returns>
        public IMessage GetMessage()
        {
            lock(_messageQueue)
            {
                while (_messageQueue.Count == 0) Monitor.Wait(_messageQueue);
                return _messageQueue.Dequeue();
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

The code for adding a message to the MessageQueue of any logger looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
        /// <para>Logs a specified <see cref="IMessage"/> in the various loggers.</para>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">The <see cref="IMessage"/> to be logged.</param>
        public void LogMessage(IMessage message)
        {
            lock(_loggerLock)
            {
                foreach (AbstractLogger logger in _loggers)
                    logger.MessageQueue.AddMessage(message);
            }
        }
```

I've placed a lock on the LogManager because the addin of a message should not conflict with adding/removing a logger from the queue. I'm sure the problem does not exists here.
The code below shows the processing routine from the XmlLogger which contains the MessageQueue object.

```
private void ProcessMessage()
{
    // This thread should be running indefinitly untill the abort is called.
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get the first message available from the Queue
            IMessage message = MessageQueue.GetMessage();

            // If we could retrieve a valid message, process it.
            if (message != null && (LogSettings.Level & message.Level) == message.Level)
            {
                // Determine the path to the logfile
                string logpath = DetermineFilePath(message.Context);

                // Write the message into the file.
                WriteMessage(logpath, message);
            }
        }
        catch(ThreadAbortException)
        {
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("InnerException caught: '{0}'", ex.Message));
        }
        finally
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to know, is this code the correct wya for using the Monitor.Pulse & Monitor.Wait routines? If not, what should I change to prevent problems?

**EDIT:** Please no questions/discussions about using ane xisting logger. It's not an option

**EDIT2**: Ran the tool from the anwser and this is the output:

> ------------------------------------ 5956 Kernel: 0 User: 156250 TenForce.Execution.Logging.Loggers.XmlLogger.ProcessMessage
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart Other Stacks:
>
> TenForce.Execution.Logging.Loggers.XmlLogger.ProcessMessage
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart

Sounds a bit too high for me...

Comment: Re the profiler usage; that *doesn't* necessarily mean that the threading is the issue; however, if you are doing lots of logging then sure: it'll be pretty busy writing them to file etc.

Comment: currently looking for a way to spead up the I/O... maybe I should load that to a thread as well and only writer every x messages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that looks ok; your dequeue correctly does a check/loop (and doesn't **assume** a pulse means there is now data, which can cause exceptions), so most of the time should be idle. Your enqueue is similar. Perhaps I'd add: only pulse if you added the first item:

```
        lock(_messageQueue)
        {
            _messageQueue.Enqueue(message);
            if(_messageQueue.Count == 1) Monitor.PulseAll(_messageQueue);
        }
```

(since otherwise, your reader is not waiting)

To investigate the high CPU, use a CPU analyzer - guesswork is usually not a good approach. Sam Saffron [has one here](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2009/11/11/Diagnosing+runaway+CPU+in+a+Net+production+application) that we use; it can be used on a production web-server (just... not all the time!)

Comment: alright, i'll see if we have such analyzers available here, and i'll add your code change as well.

Comment: Oh question: If I do not pulse anymore then, won't the threads wait indefinitly in the queue? or will they automatially recehck after some time?

Comment: @Neko a pulse only wakes things that are actually waiting. The only way something is waiting is if it found (inside the lock) that the queue was empty. In a single reader scenario, I can't see any situation that would result in the reader waiting while there is data - so: if there was already data, there is no point doing a pulse.

Comment: @NekoNova emphasis: I didn't say "don't pulse"; I said "don't pulse if the queue already had data", which we know means that nobody is sleeping

Comment: I've added some feedback from the tool, it seems the routine does cause a problem...

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any weird usages in the code you posted, you lock on a readonly object created in the constructor, and the threads that `Wait()` exit the lock's context almost immediately after acquiring the lock.

Also, threads stuck in a `Wait()` should not cause the processor utilization to go up.

Of course it's easier to spot a problem than to verify that "everything is ok" - if it's easy to reproduce you could write an empty log implementation and see if the problem persists, for instance.

Comment: i'll definitly give that approach a go. The odd thing is that our dev systems do not suffer from this issue, only the testing systems

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to write your own logging library? There are several mature, open-source loggers out there that have been exhaustively tested in production and so are unlikely to cause any problems. This is an answer to your last question ('What should I change...'), and I'd recommend NLog.

PS To address remarks about my answer not being relevant to the subject
Here are the problems I see with this code

1. It will log no more than 10 messages per second (thread.sleep)
2. Exclusive locking does not allow parallel logging from multiple threads so in effect you serialize all logger calls
3. Opening and closing a file on each log message is not the fastest solution
   .
4. There may be problems if you use more than one logging thread (look at the dequeue)

Comment: yes, I'm sure that I want/need my own logging. I cannot go into the details as to why (and I don't want to), but we have worked for years with log4net, and we've gotten sick of it, ebcause we lost ALOT of logging data due the way our background infrastructure works.

Comment: this does not **in any way** discuss any of the points from the question, and should be a comment IMO

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to know, is this code the correct wya for using the
>   Monitor.Pulse & Monitor.Wait routines?

Yes, your code will work. The big red flag I always look for is rechecking the wait condition after calling `Monitor.Wait`. If you do not recheck the condition then another consumer could swipe the last item leaving the current consumer trying to take from an empty queue.

> If not, what should I change to prevent problems?

Like I said, your code will work. But, it is not optimal if there are multiple consumers. `PulseAll` transfers every thread in the waiting queue into the ready queue. So if you add just one item to the queue all threads will wake up and compete for that single item.

The producer-consumer pattern generally works better with the `Pulse` call. If only a single item gets queued then only a single thread wakes up. If multiple items get queued in rapid succession then multiple threads wake up to process the queue. It is important to note that using `Pulse`, assuming it is called everytime and not just when `Queue.Count == 1` is still safe for multiple producers and multiple consumers.

I have an additional unrelated comment based on the code your posted. Do not use `Thread.Abort` to terminate threads. It is very difficult to deal with and can lead to data corruption in the current app domain because the `ThreadAbortException` gets injected at unpredictable points in the execution sequence of the thread. A better mechanism in your case would be to queue a `null` item as a signal to terminate the worker threads. You would queue one `null` item for each worker thread.

Comment: I'll deffo change the threadAbort stuff. probably set a boolean flag or something

Comment: @NekoNova: The boolean flag is fine, but you'll have to `PulseAll` after setting it so that all worker threads pick it up right away.